# Make Awesome keep certain windows in floating mode

Tags: awesome-wm

I've tried using the Awesome Window Manager, and although I like it, I can't currently migrate to it because of an issue with one program: [Xpad](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xpad/). It creates undecorated notepad widgets on the desktop by calling [`gtk_window_set_decorated ()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-decorated). It seems that since Awesome doesn't decorate windows, it doesn't respond to this function. Instead it treats clients that use this function as normal windows, stretching them across the entire screen when it starts and ruining my pixel-accurate configuration.

How can I ensure that I can use Xpad in an Awesome session without it changing the positions or dimensions of the pads, and that the configuration will be as I left it when I switch back to my old window manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could find a [rule](https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Understanding_Rules) to treat each XPad window floating : 
https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/FAQ#How_to_start_clients_on_specific_tags_and_others_as_floating.3F

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this earlier. That seems to solve the problem as long as I don't change layouts while the pad is on the screen. Now I just need to re-learn Awesome's basic functions...

Comment: Perfect example of how links are worthless answers in the long run (link is dead) :(

Answer (score 4):

In [`rc.lua`](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/HEAD/awesomerc.lua), you can find the `awful.rules.rule` table. Simply add applications to the `-- Floating clients.` section.

To make `MPlayer` always float, add `"MPlayer",` to the `class` table, like so:

```
awful.rules.rules = {
    -- All clients will match this rule.
    { rule = { },
      properties = { border_width = 0, --beautiful.border_width,
                     border_color = beautiful.border_normal,
                     focus = awful.client.focus.filter,
                     raise = true,
                     keys = clientkeys,
                     buttons = clientbuttons,
                     screen = awful.screen.preferred,
                     placement = awful.placement.no_overlap+awful.placement.no_offscreen
     }
    },

    -- Floating clients.
    { rule_any = {
        instance = {
          "DTA",  -- Firefox addon DownThemAll.
          "copyq",  -- Includes session name in class.
        },
        class = {
          "Arandr",
          "Gpick",
          "Kruler",
          "MessageWin",  -- kalarm.
          "MPlayer",
          "Sxiv",
          "Wpa_gui",
          "pinentry",
          "veromix",
          "xtightvncviewer"},

        name = {
          "Event Tester",  -- xev.
        },
        role = {
          "AlarmWindow",  -- Thunderbird's calendar.
          "pop-up",       -- e.g. Google Chrome's (detached) Developer Tools.
        }
      }, properties = { floating = true }},
```

Then restart awesome.

This is true as of 4.0